# PowerShell File watcher to run constantly as service

Tags: powershell, triggers, monitoring

I need a bit of help with powershell scripting. I Have a file watcher.ps1 which monitors file change in sms.txt and triggers moma.ps1. So here is what I have now:

```
$File = "C:\Users\Ray\Desktop\sms.txt"
$Action = 'C:\Users\Ray\Desktop\moma.ps1'
$global:FileChanged = $false


function Wait-FileChange {
    param(
        [string]$File,
        [string]$Action
         )
    $FilePath = Split-Path $File -Parent
    $FileName = Split-Path $File -Leaf
    $ScriptBlock = [scriptblock]::Create($Action)

    $Watcher = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $FilePath, $FileName -Property @{ 
        IncludeSubdirectories = $false
        EnableRaisingEvents = $true
    }
    $onChange = Register-ObjectEvent $Watcher Changed -Action {$global:FileChanged = $true}

    while ($global:FileChanged -eq $false){
        Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100
    }

    & $ScriptBlock 
    Unregister-Event -SubscriptionId $onChange.Id
}

Wait-FileChange -File $File -Action $Action
```

The problem is that the file needs to be monitored constantly every 15 seconds or so. With this script, it ends monitoring after change in file has occurred.
Also, I would prefer if this script wold run as service, and auto start when windows does.
Could someone guide me in right direction with this?

New to this. Cheers

Comment: You just have to put it in a WHILE loop so that it will run constantly.  And you can set it to run as a Scheduled Task that runs at startup.

Comment: where do I add while loop? In my code? Whats the correct syntax

Answer (score 2):

```
while($True)
{
    $global:FileChanged = $false
    Wait-FileChange -File $File -Action $Action
}
```

This worked for me.  There is probably a "better" way.

You also need to make sure that the .ps1 script that $Action refers to ends with `return`

To make it run all of the time, create a Scheduled Task that runs at startup.

Comment: the problem with this is, that after triggering script, it wont wait for action anymore. And will exit script, instead of waiting for more changes.

Comment: It worked for me.  I opened the file in notepad and saved it numerous times, and it ran the $Action script each time I saved it.  You have to end the action script ('C:\Users\Ray\Desktop\moma.ps1') with `return` or else control will never return to the calling script.